# Sails js rest api date range

Tags: sails.js

I have a sails api with the created date formatted like

```
"createdAt": "2018-11-01T11:49:53.700Z",
```

i can get the contains filtering on a field working e.g

```
api2/items?status=IN_PROGRESS
```

but can't get the date range working, have tried the following

```
api2/items?createdAt={'>=":2018-11-01T11:49:53.700Z, '<=":2018-11-01T11:49:53.700Z}

/api2/items?where={createdAt: { '>=': 2018-11-01T11:49:53.700Z, '<=': 2018-11-01T11:49:53.700Z }}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe waterline supports this type of query on a datetime field. I would urge you to instead store these as a number (the unix time), which you will more easily be able to do such queries. When you want to format these items for display, you can use moment.js to help out.

Comment: Thanks, thats what the node developer guy said but that seems backwards to me. Why not store date time as datetime? this must be possible, you can do it on json-server

Comment: When it comes down to it, the formatted datetime is friendly for humans to look at and make sense of, but it's kind of a nuisance for machines. For your database to make a query like that, underneath the covers it will have to convert each datetime into a number then make the comparison. To me, it makes sense that when it's machines interacting with the thing, have it as a number. When humans need to interact with it (like displaying it on the page), then you format it. I don't know if this is a satisfying explanation, but I assume this is thinking of developers of Waterline.